# @angular/cli ng serve hangs after some time of working

Tags: angular, ubuntu, angular-cli

I've been developing with angular since @angular/cli@5 and `ng serve` always worked without any problem but recently I updated to 7.0.0 and create a project with angular 7.0.0 and I noticed that after some time of working, angular no longer sees the changes in files. Also refreshing the chrome tab (which the project is served in) will result in infinite spinning.

I thought the problem is with the ~7.0.0 version but when I started working with one of my older projects with version ~6.0.0, the problem existed. I reinstalled @angular/cli@6.2.6 globally but the problem persists.

When this problem happens, pressing `ctrl+c` will write `^C` in terminal but it doesn't stop the `ng serve` command. Pressing the keys again will result in this output:

> `^C^C[1]    3080 terminated  npm start`

And of course the port will be blocked.

I use ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Which version of npm are you using?

Comment: @AliTurabAbbasi npm v6.4.1 and node v11.0.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't understand the reason for this problem but found the solution.
I noticed that the problem occurs after updating `scss` files, so I found out this should be a problem with `node-sass` as there were some changes related to `node-sass` in angular v7.0.0. running `npm i -D node-sass` (v4.10.0) solved the problem. Also I think that [this issue](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2230) is related to this problem.